# Perl Mechanize: Can't log in

Tags: perl, web-scraping, mechanize

There's a site I'm trying to log into via Perl's Mechanize module.  The target website (simplified) looks like:

```
<form action="https://domain/signin" id="signInForm" name="signInForm" method="post" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
<input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
<input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
<input type="hidden" value="" id="url" name="url">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="code" id="code">
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

I've tried three methods.  The first two involve submitting a form.  The last (not posted here) involves directly making a POST request.  So far, no success.  I'm posting the code.  Assume $loginURL, $login, $pass, and $url are all set correctly.  Also, assume string_to_file() is defined correctly as well.  Here's method 1:

```
sub login1()
{
   my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

   $mech->cookie_jar( HTTP::Cookies->new() );
   $mech->get( $loginURL );
   $mech->form_name('signInForm');
   $mech->field('email' => $email);
   $mech->field('password' => $password);
   my $result = $mech->submit();

   unless( $result->is_success() )
   {
      string_to_file( $result->status_line, 'login1_failure.html');
      die "login1 failed"
   }
   string_to_file( $mech->content(), 'login1_success.html');

   $result = $mech->get( $url );
   unless( $result->is_success() )
   {
      string_to_file( $result->status_line, 'page1_failure.html');
      die "page1 failed"
   }
   string_to_file( $mech->content(), 'page1_success.html');
}
```

And here's method 2:

```
sub login2()
{
   my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

   $mech->cookie_jar( HTTP::Cookies->new() );
   $mech->get( $loginURL );
   my $result = $mech->submit_form(
      form_name => 'signInForm',
      fields => { email => $email, password => $password }
   );

   unless( $result->is_success )
   {
      string_to_file( $result->status_line, 'login2_failure.html');
      die "login2 failed"
   }
   string_to_file( $result->decoded_content, 'login2_success.html');

   $result = $mech->get( $url );
   unless( $result->is_success() )
   {
      string_to_file( $result->status_line, 'page2_failure.html');
      die "page2 failed"
   }
   string_to_file( $mech->content(), 'page2_success.html');
}
```

The end result is that the files login1_success, login2_success, page1_success, and page2_success are all created, so supposedly no failures.  However, when I look at the contents of these files, the authentication definitely didn't work.  I'm looking at a version of $url that one sees when one is not an authenticated upgraded user (which I am).  I've made sure the login works by hand.

I *just* learned Perl Mechanize, so perhaps there's something obvious I'm not seeing.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried changing `$mech->agent('Mozilla')` or similar? Does it work from a browser? How is the request coming from your browser different to the one coming from the script?

Comment: Just tried changing the agent to something known.  Great suggestion, but no dice.  It does work from a browser.  I really, really wish I knew!

Comment: So, try comparing the requests. If your browser doesn't show it, use a tool like wireshark to analyze them.

Comment: Why do you use `login` and `pwd` as field names instead of `email` and `password` ? Also, `$mech->submit()` might be better than `$mech->click()`

Comment: @choroba Oh, I understand you now.  In my Googling I stumbled across eavesdropping on the POST communication.  There were 4 POST variables, two being empty, email which had my email address encoded (I think @ becomes a %20 or something like that) and the password.  This is what led me to try simulating the POST request, which I mentioned.

I'm more inclined to believe that I'm doing something wrong with Mechanize once I submit the form since I'm very inexperienced with this library.  I was hoping that maybe you can't just navigate to another URL once you authenticate, or something like that.

Comment: @Dada Whoa, nice catch.  It doesn't fix the immediate problem, but it wouldn't work unless the variable names got changed.  Thank you for pointing that out!  I'm going to modify the code in my question to reflect what I have now.  It may still not work, but I feel incrementally closer to the answer!  Thanks!

Comment: `%20` is a space. That's URL encoding, also called percent encoding. That would typically be in the URL, not in the POST data.

Comment: @simbabque by default forms are encoded as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which does use URL encoding even in the post data